"Powershell doesn't open and returns error: The initializer for type 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState' threw an exception."
I downloaded VS Code to start using Python. I installed Python, the extensions, and started coding. After installing some libraries via 'pip', I needed to install 'requests'. However, after installing this 'requests' library, my terminal in VS Code no longer opens, and the error that appears is just this: 'terminated with exit code: -65536.'
I tried to open my own native PowerShell but it also doesn't open anymore. I uninstalled VS Code, Python, extensions, libraries, and nothing. I tried to reset PowerShell to factory settings, but still nothing.

Error indicates the library could not load.  May be the type is wrong (x86, x32, x64).  I would check Event Viewer to see if there are any errors.

Try following

Download PsExec from this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) and extract the PSTools. zip file.
Open command prompt as the administrator.
Navigate to the PsExec.exe path.
Execute the following command: psexec -i -s powershell.exe. ...
Execute the command whoami and check if it is running as SYSTEM user.

