Terminal is not opening in visual studio code
The terminal process
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"  terminated with exit code: -65536.
I am geting only this above message can anyone help me..
I want help ,please help me .I have to complete my project

Are you running a Powershell script when this happens? If so, do you know what it was doing before you got this error? Can you edit the post to include this information. The script can be delimited by triple-back-ticks for readability.

potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78331123/11107541
