The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: -65536
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: -65536. When i open my terminal in vs code i got this error and my terminal closed why i dont know Can any body tell me about the problem sollution ?
I expect that my terminal is start working and my powershell also

The error is really 0xFFFF0000 : See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1322441/how-to-fix-system-net-servicepointmanager-error-wh

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78487981/11107541
